# Давеча — это когда?

Tags: значение-слов

Мне всегда казалось, что "давеча" — это просто "недавно". Но, может быть, у этого слова есть конкретное значение?
Так когда же это — давеча?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Так и есть, только на конце слова А.

ДА́ВЕЧА, нареч. (прост.). Недавно. Помните, давеча мы об этом говорили. «Пред кем я давеча так страстно и так низко был расточитель нежных слов!» Грибоедов.

Толковый словарь Ушакова. Д.Н. Ушаков. 1935-1940.

В словаре Ожегова есть еще добавление: незадолго до момента разговора